# Instantiate a new model through interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, model

I have a method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
{
    //model = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();
    VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
    balieUser = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();
   
    balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode);
    ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    if (!balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
        return View(model);
    }
    return View();
}
```

this is the Interface:

```
public interface VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser: IUserStateApi
{
    bool LoginBalieUser(string username);
}
```

And this is the model:

```
public class V_LoginModel_BalieUser:LoginModel
{
    public string BalieCode { get; set; }
}
```

But I get on this line:

```
balieUser = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();
```

this error:

> Code   Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>
> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Account.V_LoginModel_BalieUser' to 'Sana.Commerce.Customization.Interfaces.VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

you mean like this:

```
public class V_LoginModel_BalieUser:LoginModel, VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser
    {

        public string BalieCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But then  I have to insert all the methods of the Interface IUserStateApi.

what ofcourse not has to be.

Comment: `V_LoginModel_BalieUser` does not implement `VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser`

Comment: @Stehpan. DO you also have a suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Do you want it to extend `VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser`? if so then `public class V_LoginModel_BalieUser : VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser` (but your need to follow some conventions, including that interfaces are prefixed with `I`)

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: What do you want to do? (its not clear what your asking)

Comment: I want to extend login model with only Username. So that a User only has to fill in a username. And not a username + password